# SQL Joining two unrelated tables with repeating records

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have two tables, for argument sake table A and table B, and I would like to join them and produce a result set that has a row from table A for each row in table B.

```
    Table A          Table B
    NumericId        Type
    Description

    Contents of A    Contents of B
    1, Starting      Operation A
    2, Completing    Operation B
    [More rows]      [NO MORE ROWS]

    Desired result set:
    1, Starting, Operation A
    1, Starting, Operation B
    2, Completing, Operation A
    2, Completing, Operation B
    ... etc. ...
    (order is irrelevant)
```

Is this possible? If so, pelase could someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` is what you are looking for

Comment: Is that a home work? What have you tried till now?

Comment: Pleas read about [`Cartesian Joins`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm) as suggested by Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from Table1 CROSS JOIN Table2;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM TAbleA CROSS JOIN TableB
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue with a cross join!

```
    select 
        a.NumericId, a.Description, b.Type
    from TableA a
    cross join TableB b
    order by
        a.NumericId, a.Description, b.Type
```

Thanks